# splitting xml ino mutiple xmls based on xml tags using java

Tags: java, xml, swing

i need to split my xml into multiple xml based on the tag  start and close. For this i tried with the following code

```
    public class XmlSplit {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    File input = new File("/home/dev702/Desktop/cadgraf-test/Data_Entry.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Data_x0020_Entry", doc,  XPathConstants.NODESET);

    int itemsPerFile = 500;
    int fileNumber = 0;
    Document currentDoc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Node rootNode;
    rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("Data_x0020_Entry");
    File currentFile = new File(fileNumber+".xml");
    for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true);
        rootNode.appendChild(imported);

        if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) {
            writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);

            rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("Data_x0020_Entry");
            currentFile = new File((++fileNumber)+".xml");
        }
    }

    writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);
}

private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));
}
}
```

In this am getting error on currentDoc.createElement. Am not able to compile this code and it is saying createElement not available.

Sample xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot
    xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ;
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Data%20Entry.xsd"
    generated="2014-02-12T14:35:47"
>
    <Data_x0020_Entry>
        <ID>1004</ID>
        <User>006Parthiban</User>
        <Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>2013-12-26T00:00:00</Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>
        <Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
        <Edition>CE City Edition</Edition>
        <Location>Bangalore</Location>
    </Data_x0020_Entry>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: can u post sample xml file for that..what error your getting stacktrace pls ... and change  Node rootNode; to Element rootNode and try

Comment: am using netbeans in that itself its showing error, on hovering this it shows "cannot find method "createElement(String)". So i wont be able to run the file

Comment: is dataroot still in your splitted xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I could not see any compilation issue in this code. Please check your import statements and verify that you have imported proper classes. the list of classes which I import are as below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u have imported `import javax.swing.text.Document;` change that to `import org.w3c.dom.Document;`

And if ur using Swing too than use fully qualified that for to create Document

like

```
 org.w3c.dom.Document  currentDoc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
```

**Update**

I think the root element should be "dataroot" for splitted xmls. and you need to change your code to generate correct number of xml files (look at below code)..look at the code below..i tested for
 int itemsPerFile = 2; ..it is working fine..

**NOTE** remove  ";" from input xml file after namespcae

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    public class XmlSplit {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    File input = new File("src/test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Data_x0020_Entry", doc,  XPathConstants.NODESET);
    int itemsPerFile = 2;
    int fileNumber = 0;
    Document currentDoc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Node rootNode;


    rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("dataroot");
    File currentFile = new File(fileNumber+".xml");
    for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true);
        rootNode.appendChild(imported);

        if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) {
            writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);
            rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("dataroot");
            currentFile = new File((++fileNumber)+".xml");
        }
        else
        {
                writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);
        }
    }

}

private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));
}
}
```

let me know if u face any issues :)

Comment: import command is the problem but when i run it wont return anything..its returning as null

Comment: so post ur sample input xml file so we can test where the problem lies

Comment: My sample XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Data%20Entry.xsd" generated="2014-02-12T14:35:47">
<Data_x0020_Entry>
<ID>1004</ID>
<User>006Parthiban</User>
<Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>2013-12-26T00:00:00</Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>
<Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
<Edition>CE City Edition</Edition>
<Location>Bangalore</Location>
</Data_x0020_Entry>
</dataroot>

Comment: am getting in print statement when i print current file:  Current file --->0.xml
rootNode file --->[Data_x0020_Entry: null]

Comment: have u refreshed the project ..the files are getting generated when i ran it... check 0.xml will be there in your project folder only.. some thing is wrong it is creating one more file 1.xml also..with empty root tags...

Comment: Yes the file is generated and could see after refresh the eclipse workspace.  one problem is XML is there a semicolon after name space xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; .. just remove it and code is working.